# using php to build phone application with phonegap

Tags: php, android, cordova

i am starting with building mobile application using html5, css3, javascript/jquery with phonegap, which i just have finished studying.
The very first application which i want to create is a registration system which will have:
1) A login form where the user will enter his id and password
2) If user is new, the form will be redirected to the registration form.

All the information will be stored in the 'mysql' database.

so, the problem which i am getting in my flow diagram of the whole process is how to check whether the user is registred or not, as for that, the user will have to directed to the server side, and will have to be redirected to the registration form, if not already registered.

Another problem which i see is whether phonegap has support for php scripts or not as i have not found any thing relating phonegap to php scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database is located on the server side the only way to reach it is to use an AJAX call to a PHP file on your server.

Then, if you want to check if a user is registred or not, you can store a token using PhoneGap's [LocalStorage API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0rc1/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage).

If you need example to check if a value is stored or not, just ask ;)